# Custom iterator implementation that can skip on next() via tail recursion

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a custom iterator that has some try/catch logic. Depending on some settings, a `.next()` call can skip the data it's processing if it encounters an exception.

What I have so far:

```
def doWork(data: InputStream): Iterator[CustomClass] = {
  val dataReader = // build reader from the input stream
  new Iterator[CustomClass] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = dataReader.next() != null

    @tailrec
    override def next(): CustomClass = {
      try {
        getData(dataReader)
      } catch {
          case NonFatal(e) if settingEnabled => throw e
          case NonFatal(_) =>
            if (hasNext) {
              next() // recursive call
            } else {
              null // <--- this is what I'm not sure of
            }
          case badexception => badexception
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering about the `case NonFatal(_)` match, where I'm trying to skip the current piece of data if a NonFatal occurs (without the setting enabled). I think tail recursion would do the trick, but I'm confused about what happens if that pattern match occurs at the very end of the iterator. I don't see a way to exhaust the iterator and say "return nothing" at the end because that doesn't make sense.

I'm using Scala version 2.11.12.

Comment: _"but I can't return null in the else due to some restrictions"_ so what should you return then? Or should you just throw the exception? or should you just stop processing?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That was badly worded by me. It would only get into that `else` if the iterator was exhausted, so it should stop processing. I think I'm confused because what if the recursive call keeps calling and catching on the same pattern match until the end? How can "nothing" be returned?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use some higher-level API like unfold:

```scala
Iterator.unfold(dataReader) { reader =>
  Option(reader.next()).map { _ =>
    Try(getData(reader)).toOption
  }
}.flatten
```

This will skip all non-fatalt exceptions, you may tune the code for your additional handling of that setting.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Scala 2.11.12

Comment: @stackoverflowflowflwofjlw you may try using `Iterator.continually(Try(Option(getData(reader))))` and then do something like `takeWhile(_.isDefined)`